# Какой метод для написания сайта лучше использовать?

Tags: php

Я читал, что некоторые используют модульное программирование используя скрипт PHPNuke. Но этот метод не очень хороший в смысле быстродействия.

Я не специалист в области написания сайтов. Мой первый сайт был на html и использовался простой метод без всяких прибамбасов. Каждая страница описывалась индивидуально.

Начиная изучать PHP узнал, что ест много скриптов. Не хочется повторять ошибки прошлого и написать сайт не правильно. Подскажите какой стиль, метод или еще что лучше использовать для написания нормального сайта. Можно указать ссылки на какой нибудь хороший скрипт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начните с того, что изучите простейшие функции, например **echo**, узнайте как создаются собственные функции с помощью **function** и изучите условные конструкции **if else**. Для начала думаю этого будет достаточно, поигравшись с ними, приступайте к изучению массивов и суперглобальных массивов.
Для справки есть прекрасный [сайт](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/).

Comment: Скажу честно, я все это знаю. Еще на заре компъютеризации изучал Бейсик, Фокал, Фортран, Асемблер для 286, Java2. Решил изучить PHP. Нового в этом языке мало что есть. Кто знает несколько языков меня поймет. А вот в дизайнах немного отстал. Я согласен с тем, что брать готовый шаблон и делеть себе сайт это тупость. Мало того, меня не устраивают готовые шаблоны и я все равно все переделываю под себя. Но зачем изобретать велосипед. Можно просто взять и подкорректировать. Я не ищу шаблон. Я ищу стиль.

Comment: в том то и дело что стиль это и есть свое программирование. как вы сверстаете блоки+как вы сможете сделать из них шаблон+ как вы сделаете ядро которое сможет юзать ваш шаблон и работать так как вы этого хотите. это и есть создание сайтов. и когда создадите такое то сами поймете что это намного приятнее юзанья чужих CMS (готовых сайтов которые только надо настроить и все)

Comment: Это да! Но я в PHP новичек и знать возможности языка пока не могу. Блочная система вроде не плохая. Я в html использовал фреймы. И как то считал, что блоками будет неплохо, но в инете сказали - тупит. Вот я и спрашиваю, а какие еще способы есть. Возможно вместо блоков как то использовать базы данных.

Comment: Москва не сразу строилась.

Comment: фреймами я делал свой первый сайт это было лет эдак 11 наверное назад а может и больше. блоками ничего не тупит, я не знаю кто мог тебе такое сказать вообще. просто сначала люди делают фреймами потом таблицами и потом только блоками когда нормально понимают верстку. далее идет обновление блоков посредством AJAX и так далее. в любом случае пока сам не попробуешь все. ничего не сможешь понять

Comment: Хочу добавить, PHP это генератор HTML.

Comment: Спасибо. Это все я уже прошел. И тоже уже лет 15 назад. Первый сайт был написан фреймами. Сейчас просто переписал текстовку. Когда познакомился с PHP - узнал много инетересного по сравнению с Java2 и javascript. Неужели вместо фреймов пришли блоки и только? Ведь у сайта есть две части. Первая неизменная и вторая варируемая. Написав один блок для неизменной части вставляем внутрь варируемую часть и все? Стили то разные есть. Возможно можно весь сайт написать переменными, а в базе менять значение переменных. Вижу пока два варианта. Есть еще какие то новшества?

Comment: PHP генератор html? Я думал, это что то по круче javascript.

Answer (score 3):

вообщето советую разрабатывать самому алгоритм обучаясь PHP. иначе вы будете не программистом а шаблонщиком юзающим сторонние CMS

Comment: Уже придумали алгоритмы. А я пока ничего придумать не могу, смотрю и сравниваю готовые CMS. Надо же как то переделать свой сайт из html в PHP. Хочется для начала узнать о каких - нибудь продвинутых технологиях. И с ними начинать работать.

Comment: для этого всего лишь берите любую CMS и сделайте ей шаблон по основе любой своей страницы и все. но так вы никогда не научитесь писать свое.

Comment: Любую не интересно. Хочется хорошую...)))
И какой бы не был шаблон, ешо все равно переделывать придется. Но смысл идеи останется. Если он стоит этого.

Comment: панацеи нет) для всего есть свое)) например джумла и многие ею довольны. другие сидят на PHP-Fusion и так далее. для инет магазинов тоже свои. и каждый будет хвалить то чем он пользуется и что умеет настроить)) мне ближе самому писать и сайты и модули))

Comment: Я сейчас тоже стал переписывать свой сайт сам, и получается блочная система. Вот тут я и задумался, а что ест лучше блочной?
А Вы как пишите сайты? Видимо тоже блоками?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте разобраться с [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). Этот фреймвёрк разработан создателями языка PHP. Я считаю, что его использование не только помогает изучить язык, но и приучает к написанию качественного, легко поддерживаемого кода.

P.S. А вообще если есть возможность возьмитесь лучше за [Python](http://www.python.org/) вместо PHP. Мне кажется, что [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) сможет решить все ваши проблемы.

Comment: Это да. Согласен. Но не думаю, что надо бросать PHP. Сразу за всем не угонишься. Для изучения PHP  мне много времени не потребуется. Потом займусь Python - ом.

Comment: Помню в свое время Java2 тоже рекламировали, но на деле оказался тупиковым языком.

Comment: Python - основной язык программирование в Google! Я думаю, это кое-что значит.

Comment: Не слышал, что сервера работают с Python. Но спорить бесполезно. Все может быть. Я еще изучаю Lisp. Ведь autoCad на Lisp написан.

Answer (score 0):

PHP + Laravel = очень низкий порог входа. Документации море, комьюнити отличное(про русское ничего не скажу)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос